# Understanding why $\int_0^1 \frac{d}{dt} g(x+t(y-x)) dt=\int_0^1 D_{y-x} g(x+t(y-x)) dt$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I'm having trouble understanding this particular identity:

\begin{equation}
g(y)-g(x)=
\int_0^1 \frac{d}{dt}g(x+t(y-x))dt=\int_0^1
D_{y-x}g(x+t(y-x))dt
\end{equation}

I understand the first equality can be obtained from a simple substitution; however, i'm failing to see the second equality.

$D_v$ here is the directional derivative in the direction of $v$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you do not say it, $g$ certainly is a function $g : \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$.

You have to show that
$$\frac{d}{dt}g(x+tv) = D_vg(x+ tv)$$
where $v = y -x$. For this equation see the recent question [confusion about chain rule in linearity proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4612510).

Comment: Thank you! The confusion came about from the fact that the author had written that g is map from R^n to R^n but has only proved the fundamental theorem of calculus for single variables. I assume the components of g, g_j, was meant to be written instead, for which the proof continues to remain valid.